# Why is the review section of my Magento product page not showing?

Tags: templates, magento, layout

Somehow the review section / tab on my product pages [is not showing up](http://www.princessly.com/ball-gown-v-neck-dropped-waist-3-4-sleeve-above-knee-chapel-wedding-dress.html#product_tabs_reviews). 
The Reviews tab section is totally empty. What could be the culprit?

I have enabled 'Price', 'Quailty' and 'Value' in Catalog -> Manage Ratings and refreshed all cache. But it still doesn't show up.

And I checked the catalog.xml in the layout folder of the current theme and the 'reviews' section IS there:

```
<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="review">
    <alias>reviews</alias>
    <title>Reviews</title>
    <block>review/product_view_list</block>
    <template>review/product/view/list_tab.phtml</template>
</action>
```

And I double checked, **/home/my_user/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/my_theme/template/review/product/view/list_tab.phtml** is there and the content of it seems quite all right. It's the review and rating form no problem.

I installed some other themes on princessly.com. Could it be them that some of the template / layout files got overwritten?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Just as I suspected, it is one of the other themes that has a module getting higher in the templating priority than that of the current theme. Renamed that module's directory name and refreshed cache. Now the reviews section is correctly showing up.

Magento is much too flexible in customizing the whole store. Unlike WordPress, where a theme has no privileges other than residing in ONE folder, Magento themes come with folders and files that can overwrite almost the entire installation, making them easily entangle with each other, resulting in unpredictable problems that are hard to trace.

Recommended practice is to install as less themes on the same Magento installation as possible. I just installed 2 and that's enough for this problem to occur that wasted me 5 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Well the module is working and enabled as you can see the link at the top.

Other themes shouldn't have overwritten anything as they should all be contained within their own theme folders.

It looks like some variation of the modern theme, and since you have the Review tab I assume you have it added in the layout file. Is the template it refers to there correct? And have you checked the file to which it refers?

So for example, in my `catalog.xml` file I have the following adding the description tab:

```
<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
  <alias>description</alias>
  <title>Product Description</title>
  <block>catalog/product_view_description</block> 
  <template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template>
</action>
```

Do you have something like this adding your review tab?

Comment: I checked the catalog.xml of the current theme and it is there: <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="review"><alias>reviews</alias><title>Reviews</title><block>review/product_view_list</block><template>review/product/view/list_tab.phtml</template></action>

Comment: and did you also check the `review/product/view/list_tab.phtml` file it refers to?

Comment: Thanks Alex for the help. Just got it sorted out.